# Why is another statement appearing once I've already finished my Java program?

Tags: java

When I run this program, "Enter the temperature to convert: " always appears after I've gotten my conversion. I tried to put in.close(); to fix it but it didn't work. What do I change in my code in order to make it work?

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
       welcome();  // function call
       System.out.println("Enter '1' to convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit \nEnter '2' to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius");
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // instantiating a scanner object  
       int choice = in.nextInt();
           
          
       if (choice ==1); { 
       System.out.println("Enter the temperature to convert: ");  
       double value = in.nextDouble();
       double temp = convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(value);
       System.out.println("Temperature in degrees Fahrenheit is " + temp);
           in.close(); 
       
       }
       
       if (choice ==2); {
       System.out.println("Enter the temperature to convert: ");   
       double value = in.nextDouble();
       double temp1 = convertFahrenheitToCelsius(value); 
       System.out.println("Temperature in degrees Celsius is " + temp1);
           in.close(); 
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fix your code formatting. Either indent by four spaces or wrap in a pair of triple back-ticks.

Comment: When I try to run it this appears: Exception in thread "main" Enter the temperature to convert: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Scanner.java:1150)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1573)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
 at convert.main(convert.java:61)
and when I try to convert F to C it only gives me F

Comment: Post details as edits to the Question rather than as Comments.

Comment: @walle Also, don't close `System.in` (or `out`), they aren't your responsibilities

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here...

```
if (choice ==2); {
---------------^
```

See the `;`?  This is terminating the `if` statement and allowing the contents of the `{...}` to be executed.  You have the same problem with `if (choice ==1); {`

You code should probably look something more like...

```
if (choice == 1)
{
    System.out.println("Enter the temperature to convert: ");
    double value = in.nextDouble();
    double temp = 0;//convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(value);
    System.out.println("Temperature in degrees Fahrenheit is " + temp);

} 
else if (choice == 2) 
{
    System.out.println("* Enter the temperature to convert: ");
    double value = in.nextDouble();
    double temp1 = 0;//convertFahrenheitToCelsius(value);
    System.out.println("Temperature in degrees Celsius is " + temp1);
}
```